# Establishing which version(s) of SSL a webserver supports

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I run several web servers and would like to establish which of my web servers support different types of SSL.

e.g TLS/SSL, SSL v2, SSLv3 etc.

Does anyone know of a tool (whether web based or installed) that I can point towards a web server and it will tell me which versions of SSL are implemented on the web server as browsers don't show this information due to the handshake being done before the browser displays the page.

The only way I can think to get this information is packet sniffing which I would like to avoid.

Thanks in advance,

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/index.html is a good tool, as it gives you not only the SSL versions supported in a significant degree of detail but also examines things like cipher strength and key exchange.

We used to use http://tlsreport.layer8.net/ but that appears to be offline.

You can also use the `openssl s_client` tool, with the following flags:
`-ssl2`, `-ssl3`, `-tls1`, `-no_ssl2`, `-no_ssl3`, and `-no_tls1`.

Comment: Couldn't this be done with openssl somehow?

Comment: Yeah, updated the answer, although that doesn't give you nearly the same degree of information as the SSL Labs Report.

Comment: excellent, ssllabs worked for what I was after. Thanks :)